# Get successive differences of rows, including both the first and last row, grouped by one or more columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the successive differences of rows of data in SQL, including differences between first and last row and `0`, where the rows are grouped by multiple columns.

I have two tables that look like this

```
Date                       Value

+------------+-------+     +------------+-------+------+------+
| Date       | Name  |     | Date       | Value | Name | Type |
+------------+-------+     +------------+-------+------+------+
| 2019-10-10 | A     |     | 2019-10-11 | 10    | A    | X    |
| 2019-10-11 | A     |     | 2019-10-12 | 11    | A    | X    |
| 2019-10-12 | A     |     | 2019-10-14 | 20    | A    | X    |
| 2019-10-13 | A     |     | 2019-10-11 | 10    | A    | Y    |
| 2019-10-14 | A     |     | 2019-10-12 | 22    | A    | Y    |
| 2019-10-15 | A     |     | 2019-10-14 | 30    | A    | Y    |
| 2019-10-10 | B     |     | 2019-10-11 | 10    | B    | X    |
| 2019-10-11 | B     |     | 2019-10-12 | 33    | B    | X    |
| 2019-10-12 | B     |     | 2019-10-14 | 40    | B    | X    |
| 2019-10-13 | B     |     | 2019-10-11 | 10    | B    | Y    |
| 2019-10-14 | B     |     | 2019-10-12 | 44    | B    | Y    |
| 2019-10-15 | B     |     | 2019-10-15 | 50    | B    | Y    |
+------------+-------+     +------------+-------+------+------+
```

The `Date` table holds the universe of dates for the different names. The `Value` table has values of different types for each name. I'd like to get a set of successive differences for every value, grouped by `Name` and `Type`.

The end result I'm looking for is

```
+------------+-------+------+-------+---------------+------------+
| Date       | Name  | Type | Value | PreviousValue | Difference |
+------------+-------+------+-------+---------------+------------+
| 2019-10-11 | A     | X    | 10    | 0             | 10         |
| 2019-10-12 | A     | X    | 11    | 10            | 1          |
| 2019-10-14 | A     | X    | 20    | 11            | 9          |
| 2019-10-15 | A     | X    | 0     | 20            | -20        |
| 2019-10-11 | A     | Y    | 10    | 0             | 10         |
| 2019-10-12 | A     | Y    | 22    | 10            | 12         |
| 2019-10-14 | A     | Y    | 30    | 22            | 8          |
| 2019-10-15 | A     | Y    | 0     | 30            | -30        |
| 2019-10-11 | B     | X    | 10    | 0             | 10         |
| 2019-10-12 | B     | X    | 33    | 10            | 23         |
| 2019-10-14 | B     | X    | 40    | 33            | 7          |
| 2019-10-15 | B     | X    | 0     | 40            | -40        |
| 2019-10-11 | B     | Y    | 10    | 0             | 10         |
| 2019-10-12 | B     | Y    | 44    | 10            | 34         |
| 2019-10-15 | B     | Y    | 50    | 44            | 10         |
+------------+-------+------+-------+---------------+------------+
```

Note that the `B`–`Y` set of rows illustrates an important point—we might have a value for the last date, in which case there's no need for an "extra" row for that set.

The closest I can get right now is

```
SELECT
    d.[Date],
    d.[Name],
    v.[Type],
    v.[Value],
    [PreviousValue] = COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY d.[Name], v.[Type] ORDER BY d.[Date]), 0),
    [Difference] = v.[Value] - COALESCE(LAG(v.[Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY d.[Name], v.[Type] ORDER BY v.[Date]), 0)
FROM
    [Dates] d
LEFT JOIN
    [Values] v
ON
    d.[Date] = v.[Date]
    AND d.[Name] = v.[Name]
```

But this doesn't produce the difference for the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some data is missing on either side, you have to make up for it somehow.

One trick is to create such missing data by carefull joining.
The example below first joines the types to the `Dates` data.  So that a `FULL JOIN` with the `Values` data can also be done on the type.

Then after adding enough COALESCE's or ISNULL's , calculating the metrics becomes easy.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [Dates](
>    [Date] DATE  NOT NULL,
>    [Name] VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY ([Date], [Name])
> );
> INSERT INTO [Dates]
> ([Date], [Name]) VALUES
>   ('2019-10-10','A')
> , ('2019-10-11','A')
> , ('2019-10-12','A')
> , ('2019-10-13','A')
> , ('2019-10-14','A')
> , ('2019-10-15','A')
> , ('2019-10-10','B')
> , ('2019-10-11','B')
> , ('2019-10-12','B')
> , ('2019-10-13','B')
> , ('2019-10-15','B')
> ;
> CREATE TABLE [Values](
>    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
>    [Date]  DATE  NOT NULL,
>    [Name] VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
>    [Value] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
>    [Type] VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
> );
> INSERT INTO [Values]
> ([Date], [Value], [Name], [Type]) VALUES
>   ('2019-10-11', 10, 'A', 'X')
> , ('2019-10-12', 11, 'A', 'X')
> , ('2019-10-14', 20, 'A', 'X')
> , ('2019-10-11', 10, 'A', 'Y')
> , ('2019-10-12', 22, 'A', 'Y')
> , ('2019-10-14', 30, 'A', 'Y')
> , ('2019-10-11', 10, 'B', 'X')
> , ('2019-10-12', 33, 'B', 'X')
> , ('2019-10-14', 40, 'B', 'X')
> , ('2019-10-11', 10, 'B', 'Y')
> , ('2019-10-12', 44, 'B', 'Y')
> , ('2019-10-15', 50, 'B', 'Y')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE_DATA AS
> (
>   SELECT 
>     [Name] = COALESCE(d.[Name],v.[Name])
>   , [Type] = COALESCE(tp.[Type],v.[Type])
>   , [Date] = COALESCE(d.[Date],v.[Date])
>   , [Value] = ISNULL(v.[Value], 0)
>   FROM [Dates] AS d
>   INNER JOIN 
>   (
>     SELECT [Name], [Type], MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
>     FROM [Values]
>     GROUP BY [Name], [Type]
>   ) AS tp
>     ON tp.[Name] = d.[Name]
>   FULL JOIN [Values] AS v
>     ON v.[Date] = d.[Date]
>    AND v.[Name] = d.[Name]
>    AND v.[Type] = tp.[Type]
>   WHERE v.[Type] IS NOT NULL
>      OR d.[Date] > tp.[Date]
> )
> SELECT 
>   [Name], [Type], [Date], [Value]
> , [PreviousValue] = ISNULL(LAG([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [Type] ORDER BY [Date]), 0)
> , [Difference] = [Value] - ISNULL(LAG([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], [Type] ORDER BY [Date]), 0)
> FROM CTE_DATA
> ORDER BY [Name], [Type], [Date]
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | Type | Date                | Value | PreviousValue | Difference
> :--- | :--- | :------------------ | ----: | ------------: | ---------:
> A    | X    | 11/10/2019 00:00:00 |    10 |             0 |         10
> A    | X    | 12/10/2019 00:00:00 |    11 |            10 |          1
> A    | X    | 14/10/2019 00:00:00 |    20 |            11 |          9
> A    | X    | 15/10/2019 00:00:00 |     0 |            20 |        -20
> A    | Y    | 11/10/2019 00:00:00 |    10 |             0 |         10
> A    | Y    | 12/10/2019 00:00:00 |    22 |            10 |         12
> A    | Y    | 14/10/2019 00:00:00 |    30 |            22 |          8
> A    | Y    | 15/10/2019 00:00:00 |     0 |            30 |        -30
> B    | X    | 11/10/2019 00:00:00 |    10 |             0 |         10
> B    | X    | 12/10/2019 00:00:00 |    33 |            10 |         23
> B    | X    | 14/10/2019 00:00:00 |    40 |            33 |          7
> B    | X    | 15/10/2019 00:00:00 |     0 |            40 |        -40
> B    | Y    | 11/10/2019 00:00:00 |    10 |             0 |         10
> B    | Y    | 12/10/2019 00:00:00 |    44 |            10 |         34
> B    | Y    | 15/10/2019 00:00:00 |    50 |            44 |          6
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9f1ab31cd4b237ac16c15e47736ef8a1)*

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lag()` with the default value argument:

```
[PreviousValue] = COALESCE(LAG(v.Value, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY d.[Name], v.[Type] ORDER BY d.[Date]), 0)
[Difference] = v.[Value] - COALESCE(LAG(v.Value, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY d.[Name], v.[Type] ORDER BY v.[Date]), 0)
```

Comment: That still doesn't seem to provide a row for the last row in a group. It means I can remove the `COALESCE`, which is nice. But I don't see it do anything besides that?

Comment: The `left join` should provide the dates you want.

Comment: I think it doesn't because of the `[Type]` column in the `LAG` partition.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to demonstrate. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9d8ea53320bed087c5af72855e55cf71